# use rest_framework_simplejwt with Django 1.11.x and Python 3.6.2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have an app that is using Django 1.9.2 and python 2.7. Now I wanted to use the simple JWT solution on a REST API and started to upgrade the app to Django 1.11.29 and Python 3.6.2. I cannot upgrade to Django 2.x at a reasonable cost  ;-)

When I use the url for access token, I am getting correctly my pair of access token and a refresh token back.

But when I use refresh token url

```
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"refresh":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3BrIjoxLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImNvbGRfc3R1ZmYiOiLimIMiLCJleHAiOjIzNDU2NywianRpIjoiZGUxMmY0ZTY3MDY4NDI3ODg5ZjE1YWMyNzcwZGEwNTEifQ.aEoAYkSJjoWH1boshQAaTkf8G3yn0kapko6HFRt7Rh4"}' \
  http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/
```

I should get back my access token like

```
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJ.........."
}
```

But I get a response like

```
{
    "username": [
        "this field is required"
    ],
    "password": [
        "this field is required"
    ]
}
```

I mocked up another super-limited Django app running under Django 2.2.2 and things behave like required.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that you are using the latest version of simple jwt which requires django 2.2 as minimum.

consider using an older version which supports django 1.11 like https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-simplejwt/4.3.0/

```
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.3.0
```